# Using "fine" instead of "okay."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

They mean roughly the same. "Fine" also means that you are agreeing but not really agreeing.

In the following situations, I think "fine" sounds better ... but I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not very sure:

> I ended up staying at home, which was fine for me.
>
> And now that he'd accomplished that feat, everything would be fine.
>
> I have to leave now, but I'm sure you'll be fine.

Is "fine" better in these examples? Why or why not?

Comment: _Fine_ in this context means _satisfactory, perfectly all right_, but **as a reply to someone making a suggestion or announcing their plans** it can be used sarcastically.

Comment: The question itself is basically a matter of opinion. But ***my*** opinion of this context is that *Things are okay, but I wouldn't go so far as to say everything is fine* could be a perfectly reasonable thing to say (the situation is at least *tolerable*, but it's far from *good*). Contrariwise, I don't think I could ever accept *Things are fine, but I wouldn't go so far as to say everything is okay.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the contexts you quote, "fine" has the same sort of meaning as "okay".

However, there is a common and idiomatic meaning of "fine" which is the subject of a whole slew of jokes about communications between men and women:

"I'm going to have a night out with the lads, get absolutely bladdered, and come roaring home at 2 in the morning and probably puke up all over the bed."

"Fine!"

One can of course tell by the tone of voice that it does *not* mean, "okay", it means, "I have given up trying to communicate my disapproval of your appalling behaviour, I can't stop you doing what you want, and whether I am still living here when you return is doubtful."

Comment: When did "OK" become "okay"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey When it crossed the pond, probably.